# The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx: Connection refused - connect(2)>

Tags: ruby, ssh, capistrano

I've searched the forums to find similar bugs but have not found a solution. I literally just deployed to my staging site 30 minutes ago. And now it is giving me an error. I've been using the same method for months now, so I have no idea what's changed.

Just running this Capistrano script: 
    `scripts/deploy staging`

And I get this error:

```
The deploy has failed with an error:   
#<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxxx: Connection refused - connect(2)>
```

Clearly an ssh issue. But why would it be working one second, then not the next?

I also don't want to mess anything up on my production server.

Comment: Could be a whole host of things, can you manually ssh into your box? Also, does your sshd configuration limit the number of simultaneous sessions?

Comment: I will check. I can't remember how to ssh manually (using Digital Ocean droplet). It was working, and I was able to connect using ssh initially... I also am not sure how to check my sshd config limitations, so I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, this is so silly. I went back to my office and it worked. It must've been blocked by the location I was at! I was trying everything. Connecting to ssh, etc wasn't working. And now it's fine.

Comment: I've seen coffee shops do strange stuff (as well as lots of corp lans/public wifi) in regards to blocking. Things like only allow 80/443 via a proxy, etc.. so that makes sense.